# Sharepoint <div> Embed Code is not working

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint, embed

I am trying to add the `<div>` based code to my company sharepoint website, but its getting an error saying they accepted only `<iframe>` based embed code. I converted `<div>` to `<iframe>`, its still not working. Seems there is a problem in my convertion. I am using margin calculator from omnicalculator website.

The actual code from website:

```
<div class="omni-calculator" data-calculator="finance/margin" data-width="300" data-config='{}' data-currency="CAD" data-show-row-controls="false" data-version="3" data-t="1653660714244">
  <div class="omni-calculator-header"></div>
  <div class="omni-calculator-footer">
    <a href="https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/margin" target="_blank"><img alt="Omni" class="omni-calculator-logo" src="https://cdn.omnicalculator.com/embed/omni-calculator-logo-long.svg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<script async src="https://cdn.omnicalculator.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

I am using the below code.

```
<div class="omni-calculator" data-calculator="finance/margin" data-width="300" data-config='{}' data-currency="CAD" data-show-row-controls="false" data-version="3" data-t="1653660714244">
  <div class="omni-calculator-header"></div>
  <div class="omni-calculator-footer">
    <iframe src="https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/margin" target="_blank"><img alt="Omni" class="omni-calculator-logo" src="https://cdn.omnicalculator.com/embed/omni-calculator-logo-long.svg" /></frame>
  </div>
</div>
<script async src="https://cdn.omnicalculator.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

I contacted the support from omnicalculator but no response from them. Please check my code.